# Multiple JSON files in one Service (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, json, http, service, get

I have a Service in my angular app which gathers a JSON file with a football team's data.

```
angular.module('UsersApp').factory('SquadService', ['$http', function($http) { 

    return $http.get('squad/squad-bournemouth.json') 
            .success(function(data) { 
              return data; 
            }) 
            .error(function(err) { 
              return err; 
            }); 
}]);
```

1. Is it possible to get the same service (SquadService) to return data from multiple JSON files?
2. Is this advisable?
3. If so, how would you make multiple `$http.get` functions in the same service? If not, would it just be a case of having a separate service for every squad array, and calling them all individually in the controller, like so...?

   ```
   bournemouthService.success(function(data) {
   $scope.bournemouthSquad = data;
   });

   arsenalService.success(function(data) {
       $scope.arsenalSquad = data;
   });

   chelseaService.success(function(data) {
           $scope.chelseaSquad = data;
   });

   // and so on...
   ```

This seems like it goes against the DRY code principle, so wanted to know if there's a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend using the angular $resource service:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024411/angular-q-how-to-chain-multiple-promises-within-and-after-a-for-loop

Comment: Gavin Palmer - thanks for the heads up on $resource. My problem is in the example I saw it was pulling in specific **objects** in an **array** (labelled with id's), in my case I want to pull in specific **arrays** from arrays. I tried this, wrapping each sub-array in an object so I could give them an id. This didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your case it would make sense to create a single function that can be re-used of each team by simply passing in the parameter, instead of creating a function for each team (what would happen when teams are relegated/promoted?):

```
angular.module('UsersApp').factory('SquadService', ['$http', function($http) { 

  var getTeam = function(url){
    return $http.get(url); // returns a promise
  };

  return { 
    getTeam : getTeam 
  }
}]);
```

And in you controller:

```
SquadService.getTeam('squad/squad-bournemouth.json').then(
  function(data){
    // successcallback
    $scope.bournemouthSquad = data;
  },
  function(error){
    // errorcallback
  });
```

I think this approach is slightly more generic as you will not have to create a new function for each team but can simply pass in the url as a parameter.


To keep all your urls in one place and make it more re-useable, you might consider placing them in a constant:

```
angular.module('UsersApp').constant('PLUrl', {
    bournemouth: 'squad/squad-bournemouth.json',
    arsenal: 'squad/squad-arsenal.json',
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like what I'm after... Two quick questions: 1) In the Service, you wrote `return getTeam : getTeam` - why not just `return getTeam`? 2) If I was to use the `.constant()` method (which looks very tidy), how would I call those url's in the controller? - Thanks

Comment: 1) You are right, you can just as well use `return getTeam`, it's just a matter of personal preferences I guess. 2) Here's an useful SO article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831323/angularjs-constants

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: Actually, I've accepted your answer as it made perfect sense to me, but I tried it and it doesn't work... I'm getting this message in my console: `TypeError: SquadService.getTeam is not a function` - I copied and pasted your code... can you spot anything that might be wrong?

Comment: Right, spotted an error in the `SquadService` return statement. Updated my answer. Also remember to inject the service into your controller. Please note that I have not actually implemented the code, but it should provide you with an outline of how to implement it. Let me know if it still does not work.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Have updated and still not working unfortunately. Console logging: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at new MainController`

Comment: Any chance you can create a plunker?

Comment: Ops. I also forgot a `return` statement in the function. Updated my answer

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you, really appreciate your help.