# Codeigninter AngularJs routing with base URL

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

i have a challenge with routing on angularJS to conform with the base url set in the config on code igniter

> base url = http://localhost:8080/example/

for example if my current url is

```
http://localhost:8080/example/details
```

and there's angular service call from the Angular controller of that page like this

```
$http.get("api/gallery/" + 4).success(function (data) {
        galleryResource.getAll().$promise.then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

the url called will be

```
http://localhost:8080/example/api/gallery/4
```

but when the url is now

```
http://localhost:8080/example/details/4
```

and thesame service is called the url that will be called will be

```
http://localhost:8080/example/details/api/gallery/4
```

my question now is, is there a way to ensure that api url does not follow the current url in the address bar for starts from the base url because with the example above i want the api url to be

```
http://localhost:8080/example/api/gallery/4
```

while am on the page with url

> http://localhost:8080/example/details/4
>   Thanks in anticipation of your responses``

Answer (score 0):

You have to get your base url or to set it as a constant in AngularJS.

something like app.constant('base_url', 'http://localhost:8080/example');

then in your javascript, the url transforms from

```
$http.get("api/gallery/" + 4)
```

to

```
$http.get(base_url + "api/gallery/" + 4)
```

here is a more detailed example of how to define an constant:
[AngularJS constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831323/angularjs-constants)

Basically you need to set a base url for your API and use it on every request. This is also useful because if you change the url of the API, maybe you separate the api from the frontend something like api.localhost.com and localhost.com , you can change your base_url to api.localhost.com and everything will work just fine.