# how to define constants for Angular JS in a different file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iife

I want to write several constants for my Angular JS app. I want to write them in a separate file and want to access them.

I have tried with IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) like this,

**constants.js**

```
var Constants = (function () {

    var allConstants = {
        "url": 'abc',
        "name": "anijit",
        "sn": "sau"
    }

    return allConstants
})();
console.log('defined constants', Constants)
```

But when I have tried to access them it show `Constants not defined` error. Where I have done the wrong thing?

I want to access them using `Constants.url` in the way and I don't want to make any `$http` call or something like that. How to achieve that?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831323/angularjs-constants

Comment: Additional examples:  http://bguiz.github.io/js-standards/angularjs/constants/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As such you are using AngularJS, you can use [Constant Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant). as a constant can be injected anywhere including configuration calls in angularjs application.

Also, as the name suggests, the constants are fixed, they get applied before other provide methods. See [$provide.constant()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) for more detail.

```
// Storing a single constant value
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.constant('appName', 'My App');

// Now we inject our constant value into a test controller
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['appName', function TestCtrl(appName) {
    console.log(appName);
}]);

// Storing multiple constant values inside of an object
// Note: values in the object mean they can be modified
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.constant('config', {
    appName: 'My App',
    appVersion: 1.0,
    apiUrl: 'http://www.facebook.com?api'
});

// Now we inject our constant value into a test controller
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['config', function TestCtrl(config) {
    console.log(config);
    console.log('App Name', config.appName);
    console.log('App Name', config.appVersion);
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **factory** (I personnaly always use storage.factory.js in my projects). Easy to inject everywhere and you can use some functions to setup your constants or change them a little bit if you want.

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('storage', storageFactory);

    function storageFactory() {
        const data = {
            serverAddress : 'http://server.address:port'
        };

        return data;       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

file 1:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', [
    'app.constants'
  ]).value('CONSTANT_EXAMPLE', 'value example')
    .value('OTHER_EXAMPLE', 'other example');

})();
```

file 2:

```
(function () {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app.example-use', [])
    .factory('example', example);

  example.$inject = ['CONSTANT_EXAMPLE']; // and others injections

  function example(CONSTANT_EXAMPLE) { // and others injections

    function getConstantExample() {
      var option = CONSTANT_EXAMPLE;
      // use ...
    }

    return {
      getConstantExample: getConstantExample
    };
  }

})();
```