# Use javascript var in AngularJS constant

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm would like to use a var from a plain old javascript file in an AngularJS constant. Is that possible. Below is what I have tried.

Javascript file:

```
"use strict";

var CONST_MAP = {
  'key': 'value'
};
```

AngularJS file:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('foo').constant('bar', {
    'test': CONST_MAP
});
```

Comment: Sorry, not an answer, but I was just wondering why you would use `var` instead of `const`.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using angular [providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers).

```js
var CONST_MAP = {
  'key': 'value'
};
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.constant('bar', {
  'test': CONST_MAP
})
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, bar) {
  console.log(bar)
  $scope.name = bar.test.key;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  {{ name }}
</div>
```

Comment: But I want my javascript var in a separate file.

Comment: You can import them to your file and use it

Comment: How do I import the javascript file?

Comment: You can import with `import { CONST_MAP  } from "./path/to/your/file"` and the same variable must be exported from the file as `export var CONST_MAP = {
  'key': 'value'
}`

Comment: I get the following error:
>> error: couldn't process source due to parse error
>> 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036138/how-to-define-constants-for-angular-js-in-a-different-file/45036383

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do it like this:

```
angular.module('foo').constant('bar', (function(){
    var CONST_MAP = {
      'key': 'value'
    };
    return {
       test: CONST_MAP
    }
}));
```

Comment: But I want my javascript var in a separate file.

Comment: Aham, than check the answer from @Nitheesh