# Extract base url from config.js AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am using a base url in all my HTML pages, I want to put this base url in a fixed file and want to extract from there. How to do it in Angular JS.
Can I please get the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The following step could be solved your problem.

> 1. You can store your all constant like URL, User, Role to constant.js file and include this file to index.html
> 2. After bootstrapping your app, store into $rootScope from constant (eg. $rootScope.url = constant. Url)
> 3. Enjoy it

Answer (score 0):

Just like you define your controller, you need to define constants.

```
app.constant('BASE_URL', 'http://www.test.com');

.controller('MyController', function (BASE_URL) {
  expect(BASE_URL).toEqual('http://www.test.com');
});
```

This will also help.
[AngularJS constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831323/angularjs-constants?answertab=votes#tab-top)